# How do I get rid of the white line after using the fill tool in krita

Tags: fill, krita, digital, outline

If I use the fill or bucket tool in Krita I end up with these white outlines. so What I am wondering is how can I get rid of the white outlines that appear after using the fill tool in Krita. it becomes frustrating to haft to paint over them every time I use the fill tool which makes my artwork look sloppy. as a side note, there was a checkbox in photoshop that turned this problem on and off.
[image]

Comment: if there is better ways of doing this feel free to add your own answers.

Comment: Usually you'd fix that in the Bucket fill tool settings - typically the "threshold" setting. This would be the same in most raster image editors, Krita, Photoshop, GIMP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. so first have a shape you want to fill in then select your fill tool or press F then go to Tool Options and change the "Grow Selection" to 1.
[image]